# C# - Visual Studio 2012 Plugin - Copy (- Paste) all Props of a class (as Xalm powertoys does)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, plugins

I need a simple plugin for visual studio 2012 that copies in my clipboard all the props of a given class that i've selected via visual studio.

Something close to what "xaml power toys" does for model classes, but xaml power toys works only with visual studio 2010.
Any Idea about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [Visual Commander](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) C# command copies to the clipboard properties of the selected class in Visual Studio text editor:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection textSelection = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    if (textSelection == null)
        return;
    EnvDTE.CodeClass codeClass = textSelection.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass] as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
    if (codeClass == null)
        return;

    string properties = "";
    foreach (CodeElement elem in codeClass.Members)
    {
        if (elem.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty)
            properties += elem.Name + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(properties);
```